# binding return and esc keys in curses library (in perl)

Tags: perl, curses

In order to bind the CTRL+Q key using Perl's Curses library, it'll be :

```
$cui->set_binding( sub {exit 0;}, "\cQ" );
```

How can I bind the ENTER and the ESC keys? Where can I find a good resource except for this one for those modules?

[A good resource for Perl Curses::UI](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MDXI/Curses-UI-0.9607/lib/Curses/UI/Tutorial.pod)

Comment: `"\r"` aka `"\x0D"`, and `"\c["` aka `"\x1B"`?

Answer (score 4):

To add to the original comment, the best resources in this case are going to be the distro's various module documentation, the source code, and the ncurses library. 
 We can see [here](https://metacpan.org/source/MARCUS/Curses-UI-0.95/lib/Curses/UI/Common.pm#L367) that `esc` and a few other keys are special cases.

As an example you would use the subroutine `Curses::UI::Common::CUI_ESC()` or `"\x1B"` as originally suggested.

We can see it in use [here](https://github.com/gdm/Curses-UI/blob/7f14eeab6cd07f1a35663fe0a0e0e771bf388e6d/lib/Curses/UI/Menubar.pm#L137)

One of the modules that seems to be quite relevant to this topic is [Curses::UI::Widget](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses::UI::Widget)

Comment: KEY_ENTER() indeed as you said and must using the relevant sub libraries as in your example. thanks